# If I refresh my Sandbox now, will it be on the Preview Release version?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh, release, pre-release, preview

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2018/08/winter-19-release-sandbox-preview-instructions.html) What happens if I refresh my sandbox now?

1. Will still be built on Winter Release 19 and stay as it is now (as we are close to the 13 October Deadline)
2. It will go to Summer 18 until the final refresh on October 13th
   (As it says to refresh after September 7th to go to Summer 18)

I am currently on Winter Preview in Instance CS80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upgrade now, your sandbox will be built on a non-preview instance, and roll back to Summer '18.

**Here's how it works:**

Sandboxes can be on "preview" or "non-preview" instances.  Preview instances automatically switch to the new version at the beginning of the **preview window** -- the period between when the new release is made available for preview in sandboxes and when it's released to production.

Regardless of whether your sandbox is on a preview or non-preview instance, if you refresh your sandbox before the beginning of the window, it will be moved to a preview instance, and be one version ahead of your production org.

Likewise -- regardless of whether you're on preview or non-preview -- if you refresh your sandbox inside the preview window, it will be moved to a non-preview instance, and be on the same version as your production org.

Being on a "preview instance" means your sandbox will be automatically switched over earlier than your production org ...but that's all. As far as refreshing your sandbox goes, all that matters is whether you're inside or outside the preview window.